# How to import an .sql file into a Postgres database?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, homestead

When I run the following command to import the sql DB into PostgreSQL,

```
psql -U homestead -h localhost <DB Name> < <backup.sql>
```

it throws the following syntax error.

```
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "sql_mode"
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "time_zone"
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `addresses` (
```

Any idea to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some small differences in syntax between mysql and postgresql. You will find lots of help while searching `mysql to postgresql`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use mysqldump to create your .sql file.
`mysqldump -u username -p --compatible=postgresql databasename > outputfile.sql`
Now you can import .sql in your postgresql database without any error.
Hope this help.